# POST array body in RESTSHARP

Tags: restsharp

I have been using RESTSHARP automating REST API test cases. So far I am familiar in using `JObject` like:

```
public IRestResponse HELPERS_POST(JObject input)
{
    ...

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    request.AddParameter("text/json", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);    

    ...
```

My problem now is I have a new API with the following information:

- Parameters: nodeIds Parameter
- Type: body
- Data Type: Array[long] or as example {[12345,23453,45332]}

I parsed the above as `JArray`.
Now I don't know what to do with this `JArray` so my `HELPERS_POST()` can use it to make a POST request.

Comment: Data Type: Array[long] example is [12345,23453,45332] no curly

Comment: I tried this.. JArray i = HELPERS_Read_InputJarray_File(input, strEdit);
......
            request = new RestRequest(api.HTTPRequestAPI, Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", auth);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddParameter("nodeIds", i, ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: Sorry just trying different things to give an idea <br\>
 request = new RestRequest(api.HTTPRequestAPI, Method.POST);<br\>
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", auth);<br\>
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;<br\>
            request.AddParameter("nodeIds", 912138, ParameterType.RequestBody);<br\>
   
I did an F12 om browser, this is what's been processed by the REST API <br\>
Request Payload<br\>
[912187,912186]<br\>
0: 912187<br\>
1: 912186<br\>

Comment: I got it to work! Use JArrray as input, then AddParameter("application/json" in request, like    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
     
 request.AddParameter("application/json", i, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        
            resp = client.Execute(request);